# React Hook Form - how to include extra metadata in submit handler

Tags: reactjs, react-hook-form

How would one submit extra data (along with the inputed values) when using React Hook Form?

```
const MyForm = () => {
    const formMethods = useForm()
    const { handleSubmit } = formMethods

    const onSubmit = (data) => {
        dispatch(doSomething(data))
    }

    return (
        <FormProvider {...formMethods}>
            <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit}>{registered form inputs here}</form>
        </FormProvider>
    )
}
```

The `data` argument of the `onSubmit` function is only what is selected or typed into input fields. However, let's say that:

1. I want to treat the values of some inputs differently than others and want to include a flag like `isSpecial` so that I do some extra processing on the value of input that I wouldn't do on another.
2. Or, let's say I want to include some other metadata along with the submitted value. For example, instead of the `id` of a selected radio button, I also want to include the display label as well.

So instead of something like the below which is what the `data` argument will currently show:

```
{
    input1: 'selected-value',
    input2: 'selected-value2',
    input3: 'This is free text input'
}
```

I might want something like:

```
{
    input1: { value: 'selected-value', label: 'Orange' },
    input2: { value: 'selected-value2', isSpecial: true },
    input3: { value: 'This is free text input' },
}
```

That way I can have some extra metadata to work with as I process these submissions prior to POSTing them to my backend.

How would I modify the `onSubmit` or the `onChange` handlers of the child input tags so as to achieve what I want?

Comment: good question: I have the same problem, I have an object with many fields, and only some of them change with the form, but I need som others to update, based on the choices the user makes. I'll post back here if I figure out a way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Your question can be answered with two variations: The one you present has the initial data structure:

```
{
    input1: { value: 'selected-value', label: 'Orange' },
    input2: { value: 'selected-value2', isSpecial: true },
    input3: { value: 'This is free text input' },
}
```

The alternative is:

```
{
    input1: { value: 'selected-value', label: 'Orange' },
    input2: { value: 'selected-value2' },
    input3: { value: 'This is free text input' },
    input2Special: true
}
```

The difference is in how you want to represent your data and handle the input. In the second case we're leaving "input2" as a simple text field.

I'm not sure what you're trying to do with `label: Orange` so I'm just ignoring it in this answer.

Now based on the form code you supplied the first variation needs to do something like this:

```
const { handleSubmit } = useForm({
  defaultValues: data
});

const onSubmit = (data) => {
  dispatch(doSomething(data));
}

const handleInput2Value = (newValue: string) {
  onChange({value: newValue, isSpecial: input2.isSpecial});
}

const initialInput2Value = (settingValue: {value: string, isSpecial: boolean}): string {
  return settingValue ? settingValue : '';
}

<form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
  <input id="input1" name="input1" type="text" />
  <input id="input2" name="input2" type="text" value={initialInput2Value(value)} onChange={handleInput2Value(value)}/>
  <input id="input3" name="input3" type="text" />
  <input type="submit"/>
</form>
```

input2 is a non-primitive data type, so it can't be represented in a form field in the normal way (like a string or a number can). So we need `initialInput2Value(...)` to get the object and get the part the you want the user to be able to edit, and put that into the field. Then when the user has changed the value, you have `handleInput2Value(...)` to turn the simple text value back into the object.

The second variation would look like this:

```
const { handleSubmit } = useForm({
  defaultValues: data
});

const [input2SpecialFm, setInput2SpecialFm] = useState(data.input2Special);

const onSubmit = (data) => {
  dispatch(doSomething(data));
}

const handleInput2Value = (newValue: string) {
  // do whatever fancy thing you want here, such as...
  setInput2SpecialFm(true)
}


<form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
  <input id="input1" name="input1" type="text" />
  <input id="input2" name="input2" type="text" onChange={handleInput2Value(value)}/>
  <input id="input3" name="input3" type="text" />
  <input id="input2Special" name="isInput2Special" type="hidden" value={input2SpecialFm} />
  <input type="submit"/>
</form>
```

here we are keeping "input2" as a simple text value, so you don't need the `initialInput2Value(...)` anymore. Instead we set a new hidden input called "input2special" and we control its value via `useState`, using `handleInput2Value(...)`

Which way you go is determined by your circumstances and whether you can capture all your variations within one complex object, or if its better to separate out fields intended as data versus meta-style fields (like isSpecial seems to be).

Anyway, these are my findings based on trial and error - there are probably better ways, but these work.